# EF Core idempotent migration script fails despite check on applied migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I am using EF Core (3.1.15).  In a previous migration (also created in 3.1.15), a column was referenced that was dropped later on. The idempotent script does check if the migration was performed on the database (which it is, and the reference still shows in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table). However the check doesn't have the expected result and the script due to the inexistent column.

**Q**: why is the inexistent column tripping the execution of the SQL script?

Script was created with

```
dotnet-ef migrations script -i -o migrations.sql
```

Relevant part of the automated script that fails, where `ReferenceToLedgerId` is the column dropped in later migration:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210612052003_CLedger')
BEGIN
    UPDATE LedgerTable SET LedgerId = ReferenceToLedgerId
END;
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid column name 'ReferenceToLedgerId'

When running the following SQL query, the result comes back as expected:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210612052003_CLedger'
```

| MigrationId | ProductVersion |
| --- | --- |
| 20210612052003_CLedger | 3.1.15 |

The database is Azure SQL Database. Script doesn't fail on local SQL dev database. A dozen migrations have been applied since then, and only now the script fails.

Below was the call that created the specific script:

```c
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE LedgerTable set LedgerId = ReferenceToLedgerId", true);
```

I tried to place the table and column names in square brackets, but that made no difference (eg. `[ReferenceToLedgerId]`.  The script fails in Azure DevOps release when using `SQLCMD` and also fails when using Azure Data Studio, both accessing the Azure SQL Database.

---

**Additional check**

I changed the script to do a quick check:

```sql
PRINT '#Before IF'
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210612052003_CLedger')
BEGIN
    PRINT '#Within IF'
    --UPDATE LedgerTable SET LedgerId = ReferenceToLedgerId
END;

PRINT '#After IF'
```

To which I get the following result:

> Started executing query at Line 1
> #Before IF #After IF
> Total execution time: 00:00:00.010

If I uncomment the `UPDATE` statement it fails again.  So I can only conclude that the code path works as intended, but that the server still checks for the existence of the column.  I am not familiar with SQL to understand why this would be, or why it only fails for this one line while the column itself is referenced in other lines of the SQL script without it failing.

Comment: *Q: what could be the cause of failure here?* Having no knowledge of your development systems and processes one can only guess. Probably somebody did an intermediate release using the same version number from code on their machine instead of code from the master branch of your repo as output by your CI/CD systems.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have changed the question to be more specific on the actual issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That batch will fail on every version of SQL Server.  eg

```
use tempdb
go
create table __EFMigrationsHistory(MigrationId nvarchar(200))
create table LedgerTable(LedgerId int)
go
insert into __EFMigrationsHistory(MigrationId) values (N'20210612052003_CLedger')
go
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210612052003_CLedger')
BEGIN
    UPDATE LedgerTable SET LedgerId = ReferenceToLedgerId
END;
```

Fails with

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'ReferenceToLedgerId'.
```

Because the batch cannot be parsed and compiled.  It's simply not legal to reference a non-existent table or column in a TSQL batch.

You can work around this by using dynamic SQL, so that the batch referencing the non-existent column is not parsed and compiled unless the migration is being applied.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("exec('UPDATE LedgerTable set LedgerId = ReferenceToLedgerId')", true);
```

This is documented here:

> Tip
>
> Use the EXEC function when a statement must be the first or only
> one in a SQL batch. It might also be needed to work around parser
> errors in idempotent migration scripts that can occur when referenced
> columns don't currently exist on a table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations

Comment: Thank you, I will call `migrationBuilder.Sql()` with an `exec` call from now.  I am still confused why this didn't trip on my local DB nor in the previous migrations, but I am happy I have a solution.  I will also read the green "tips" in Microsoft documentation with more care from now on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations

Comment: When the output of the op's `dotnet-ef migrations script -i -o migrations.sql` includes many `GO`'s(batches).  Are we supposed to split string on GO(lines) and pass each as `migrationBuilder.Sql("exec(...` ?   Sure seems like I shouldn't being doing this but am following this recomendation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts:~:text=Consider%20generating%20SQL%20scripts